# BroadcastReceiver unregister error

Tags: java, android, class, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to unregister the broadcastreceiver when a switch is disabled. I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
Switch BTswitch = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.BTswitch);
    BTswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    registerReceiver(new mReceiver(), new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
                }
            else {
                    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, mReceiver.class);
                    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(component , PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED , PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
                }
        }
    });
```

I have also tried:

```
unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

Here is my android manifest:

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".mReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is the mReceiver.java file:

```
public class mReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private DevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager;
private ComponentName mComponentName;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
```

How to unregister. This code do not unregister the broadcstreciver. It is always running.

Comment: have you tried to use  [unregisterReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)) to unregister?

Comment: yes, i have tried: unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

Answer (score 0):

Actually it keeps creating multiple instances (`mReceiver` instance) whenever you do switching:

```
registerReceiver(new mReceiver(), new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
                }
```

If you can afford, you can modify your codes to just use one instance of the `mReceiver`

```
final Register receiver = new mReceiver();

@Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked){
                    registerReceiver(receiver , new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
                }
```

so that when you unregister the receiver, you unregister the same `mReceiver`.

```
unregisterReceiver (receiver);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. To unregister, should I use PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
                    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, mReceiver.class);
                    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(component , PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED , PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
            or unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

Comment: No, just *unregisterReceiver (receiver)*, it works most of the time